# Fixing Weight Problem While Rigging Canine Mouth?

Tags: rigging, vertex-weights

I tried to make a canine mouth and rig it:
[image: nonposed canine mouth]

Then, I encountered a problem. When I moved the rig, the teeth also changed its shape. I feel like there's something wrong with the weight. Is there any way to fix the weight, or did I miss something important?
[image: posed canine mouth]

[image: posed2]

Comment: You can remove these vertices from all vertex groups then assign to the right group, in the Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups

Comment: @moonboots Okay, let me try that

Comment: to remove from all groups, select the tooth vertices in Edit mode then on the right of the Vertex Groups list there's a down arrow, click on it and Remove From All Groups

Comment: @moonboots Thanks! It worked. I finally understand how it works :D

Comment: ok, great then  ;)